# Parse JSON without array

Tags: android, json

I need to parse JSON. Unfortunately, I couldn't get name and rate from the JSON string as usual method described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613028/how-to-parse-json-array-without-json-object-title-in-android). Also, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154735/parse-json-without-using-array-name) doesn't help me.

```
{"usd":
    {"code":"USD",
     "alphaCode":"USD",
     "numericCode":"840",
     "name":"U.S. Dollar",
     "rate":1.0857128644692,
     "date":"Mon, 21 Dec 2015 12:00:01 GMT"},
 "gbp":
    {"code":"GBP",
     "alphaCode":"GBP",
     "numericCode":"826",
     "name":"U.K. Pound Sterling",
     "rate":0.72830809326194,
     "date":"Mon, 21 Dec 2015 12:00:01 GMT"},
  "cad":
     {"code":"CAD",
      "alphaCode":"CAD",
      "numericCode":"124",
      "name":"Canadian Dollar",
      "rate":1.5123600265482,
      "date":"Mon, 21 Dec 2015 12:00:01 GMT"}
}
```

Result:

"U.S. Dollar" "1.0857128644692"

"Canadian Dollar" "1.5123600265482"

Comment: Please See my Answer on this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397172/android-issue-with-jsonarray-parsing).
I hope you are clear with my Step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this solution

```
 try {

        JSONObject MainJsonObject = new JSONObject("Your Sting input data");

        Iterator keyNames = MainJsonObject.keys();

        while (keyNames.hasNext()) {

            String keyname = (String) keyNames.next();

            JSONObject jsonObject = MainJsonObject.getJSONObject(keyname);

            // parse this this jsonObjectas you required

        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```